# Symfony 1.4 - How to get an yml config file parameter from another yml config file

Tags: symfony-1.4, yaml

I need to use an yml config file parameter into another yml config file in Symfony 1.4, and I don't know how to do this.

In app.yml I have defined parameters like "ldap ip" or "ldap domain", and theese parameters are also used in LDAPauth.yml. For that reason, I want to unify it:

**app.yml:**

```
    all:
      ldap:
        ip: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
        domain: ou=XXXXXX, ou=......
```

**LDAPAuth.yml:**

```
    adLDAP: 
        base_dn: ou=XXXXXX, ou=......
        domain_controllers:
          - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I tried this in LDAPAut.yml, but doesn't work:

**LDAPAuth.yml:**

```
    adLDAP: 
        base_dn: %APP_LDAP_IP%
        domain_controllers:
          - %APP_LDAP_DOMAIN%
```

I would appreciate if anybody knows how to make this works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute PHP code inside a yml (yep crazy but so useful sometimes).

In your case, since data inside `app.yml` file are accessible using `sfConfig::get`, you can do:

```
adLDAP: 
    base_dn: <?php echo sfConfig::get('app_ldap_domain')."\n"; ?>
    domain_controllers:
      - <?php echo sfConfig::get('app_ldap_ip')."\n"; ?>
```

The `"\n"` at the end is to write a line return to no break the yml syntax.

Comment: Thanks mate, I didn't know that I could use php code inside yml file. Thanks, it worked perfectly!

Comment: It may work like a charm but a yml is a config file, there should not be any logic on it so executing PHP inside a config file "smells". Just sayin'